# Iron-router onbeforeAction i don't understand the docs. Any help better examples? Meteor 1.0.2.1

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I don't understand how to code for this. I looked at examples from docs but not clear. I want to render a route only when user is logged in. I have a bunch of `Router.routes` defined and thing work fine until i try to implement various form of `onBeforeAction`. This is the example i'm trying. I want to apply to only several specific pages.

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
only: ["newQuestions"]
if (!Meteor.user()) {
    This.render('home');
} else {
    this.next();
}
});

Router.route('/newQuestions', function() {
    this.render('nav', {to: 'nav'});
    this.render('footer', {to: 'footer'});
    this.render('newQuestions');
}, {
    name: 'newQuestions'            
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of in `onbeforeAction` do it in router handler only, like following

```
Router.route('/newQuestions', function() {
 if (Meteor.user()) {
    this.render('nav', {to: 'nav'});
    this.render('footer', {to: 'footer'});
    this.render('newQuestions');
 } else {
  //show rendering of login page or something here, if any 
  // like this.render('<your-login-tempalte>')
 }
}, {
    name: 'newQuestions'            
});
```